# Need help setting up mail DNS records

Tags: domain-name-system, mx-record

We are hosting our web site on host monster, but want our email to continue to be hosted at the old site.  Our domain points to the hostmonster DNS servers, but I can't figure out the right configuration for the remote email servers.  We have one MX entry, which is

```
priority: 0
domain: ourdomain.com
```

And then we have these DNS entries ...

```
name: mail.ourdomain.com
ttl: 14400
class: IN
type: A
record: old.host.ip.address

name: mail1.ourdomain.com
ttl: 14400
class: IN
type: A
record: old.host.secondip.address
```

Can someone tell me what I need to add/edit to get mail to correctly route to our old host?

Comment: Can you post the full MX RR? `dig -t mx ourdomain.com`

Answer (score 1):

Because your MX record is pointing to domain.com not mail.domain.com you need to fix that and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

change your mx record from ourdomain.com. to mail.ourdomain.com. and its ready to go